# How to redirect by common routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have the action

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
```

I need redirect to action Index if id null. How to do this in routing?

I tried:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Redirect from empty controller/edit to controller/list",
                url: "{controller}/Edit",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
```

but it not helped.

Comment: Redirection and routing are not the same thing. Do you want Index action to respond to the request when there is no id parameter or do you want to send a redirection response to http://example.org/MyController/Index url from Edit action?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm not sure on routing, but if it helps you could use the `return RedirectToAction("index", "home");` (Where index is your action method and home is the controller you want to access it on).

Answer (score 0):

Redirection is simple. You can check if `id` parameter is present by making it nullable. You don't need routing configuration. This will redirect the user to http://example.org/Home when he/she sends a request to http://example.org/Home/Edit

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    //other logic
}
```

If you don't want redirection and make Index action respond to a request with http://example.org/Home/Edit URL, you can create a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("HomeEdit", 
                "Home/Edit", new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"});
```

Just make sure this route is above the default route in RouteConfig.

Comment: redirect in action it that I want avoid. second example is special case, I need common case.

Comment: You don't need anything for common case(http://example.org/Home/Edit/3). Default route will take care of that.

Comment: I need Home/Edit/ -> redirect to Home/Index

Comment: Then you only need the first part of my post.